# dynamically store li id in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my codes lis are generate dynamically and each li has special id.
I want to store each `li` "id" in the one array

**this is js codes**

```
var i=0;
$("ul#portfolio li").each(function(eval){
    var idd = new Array();
        idd[i]=$(this).attr("id");
    i++;
});
```

but it dosn't work.

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
    <!-- Dynamically generated li -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any LI elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var idd = $("#portfolio li").map(function(eval){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

---

In your case your array is local to the callback, so every iteration of the each callback you are creating a new array instead of adding the item to an existing array

```
var idd = new Array();
$("#portfolio li").each(function (eval) {
    idd.push(this.id)
});
```

- Make sure your script is running after the target elements are loaded to the dom(May be by using a dom ready handler)
- Use `this.id` which is the same as `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: the log which consol.log is return to me show that just one cell is become full and that is array(1), I cant find why this problem happened

Comment: @mimi you need to run the code after the `li` elements are added to the `ul`

Comment: I checked what u said but it has same problem

Answer (score 2):

You Can try This Also

```
$(document).ready(function()
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        $('#portfolio').append("<li id='"+ i +"'>"+ i  +"</li>");
    }

    var idArray=new Array();
        $('#portfolio li').each(function(ind,val){
        idArray.push(this.id)

        });

    console.log(idArray);
});
```